# Imagesizes Wordpress

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with the imagesizes in Wordpress. I only worked once with Wordpress and I am a real noob at this topic. My website doesn't display my image if i define the imagesize:

```
    <img src="<?php echo get_field("bild")["sizes"]["large"]; ?>">
```

but if I insert the code without the imagesize-part, the image is displayed:

```
    <img src="<?php echo get_field("bild"); ?>">
```

If I define the imagesize (first example) the image isn't displayed and this shows up in the console:

```
    <br />
    <b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'sizes' in <b>/home/u893440311/public_html/wp-content/themes/JWHomepage/index.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
```

```
    <b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'large' in <b>/home/u893440311/public_html/wp-content/themes/JWHomepage/index.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
    h
```

I really have no idea how to fix this.